# First argument "email" must be a valid string."

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm recently working in a project using Angular2 with material component and developing a sigun & login form attached to Firebase. The things is, whenever the signin button is clicked it should give an error "ERROR M {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."

```
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="onSignup(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <label class="registr">Registration Form</label>
        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
          <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
          </mat-form-field></td>

          <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
          </mat-form-field></td>
          </tr></table>

          <mat-form-field>
              <input type="email" matInput placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" name="email" [formControl]="email" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Enter your password" id="password" name="password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
            <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info d-none d-lg-block m-l-15" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
```

> signupcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  hide = true;
  //name:string = "irf";
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
        this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
            '';
  }

  onSignup(form: NgForm) {
    //console.log(this.form)
    //return
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signupUser(email, password);
      }

   }
```

auth.service.ts

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  token: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      )
  }

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(
        response => {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
            .then(
              (token: string) => this.token = token
            )
        }
      )
      .catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.token != null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You didn't declare your form into your component.

2 - You're duplicating the form logic by using a form in your HTML and a form control in your component.

3 - If you want to keep your code, yo ushould consider renaming your form control, to let's say `emailFormControl`, to avoid any confusion with your form.

4 - Once you have renamed your form control, you should change your HTMl to cope with your new model.

5 - It would be nice to post the actual error trace, as well as your HTTP call (in your dev tools), so that we can actually see the issue, and not guess.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally code work properly as what i want.